# Is it better to have more degrees of freedom or less?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, sample-size, degrees-of-freedom

The concept of degrees of freedom appears in many places in statistics. Yet I still don't understand what is the role of degrees of freedom. Why can we just use sample size (and we need to decrease it with something)? In general, is it better when my model have more degrees of freedom?

Comment: It depends on context and what you are trying to do.  Sometimes it is associated with sample size, and bigger samples are usually better.  At other times it is associated with the number of different parameters you can adjust and having more can lead to overfitting

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to provide a definition of degrees of freedom [here](https://hbiostat.org/doc/glossary.pdf):

---

This has somewhat different meanings depending on the context. In general, d.f. is the number of “free floating” parameters or the number of opportunities a statistical estimator or method was given. For a continuous variable Y , there are two types of d.f.: numerator d.f. and denominator d.f. Denominator d.f. is also called error d.f. and is the sample size minus the number of parameters needing to be estimated. It is the denominator of a variance estimator. Numerator d.f. is more aligned with opportunities and is the number of parameters currently being considered/tested. For example, in a “chunk” test for testing whether either height or weight is associated with blood pressure, the test has 2 d.f. if linearity and absence of interaction are assumed. In a traditional ANOVA comparing 4 groups, the comparisons have 3 d.f. because any 3 differences involving the 4 means or combinations of means will uniquely define all possible differences in the 4. One can say that the d.f. for a hypothesis is the number of opportunities one gives associations to be present (relationships to be non-flat), which is the same as the number of restrictions one needs to place on parameters so that
the null hypothesis of no association (flat relationships) holds.

---

More "error" degrees of freedom is always good (higher sample size).  More "model/numerator/hypothesis" d.f. may possibly be good; it indicates more honesty about the complexity of the model and in the frequentist world allows for a perfect multiplicity adjustment by penalizing for the number of opportunities.  But after a certain point statistical power will decline with increasing d.f. (number of parameters being tested).